# System.StackOverflow with Me.Cursor

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that utilizes `Me.Cursor = <cursor_type>` in several places without any error.

But in a certain form, with neither special instructions nor huge size, this instruction is raising a System.StackOverflow in my Visual Studio 2013.

There is no special reason, since the error occurs in the CLICK event of a button and that instruction is the first line of the Click event.

Do you know what can be happen here?

```
Private Sub TestInternoServer_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TestInternoServer.Click

      Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
      Me.Refresh()
```

Comment: The code above should be fine... I am more concered about setting `Me.Cursor = ""` that shouldnt compile... Show us the exception please...

Comment: Can you show the full exception with stack trace?

Comment: I have hundreds of the same lines: System.dll!System.ComponentModel.Component.Events.get()
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnCursorChanged(System.EventArgs e)
MetroFramework.dll!MetroFramework.Controls.MetroTextBox.BaseTextBoxCursorChanged(object sender = {Text = Evaluation of method System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Text() calls into native method System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.GetWindowTextLength(). Evaluation of native methods in this context is not supported.}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs})

Comment: The exception is just: 'System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.dll'

Comment: Interesting note that if I utilize "Application.UseWaitCursor = True" instead "Me.Cursor = WaitCursor" the error does not rise. But, even if I delete any cursor change code but I keep the "Me.Cursor = Default" at the end of the button´s routine, the error rises at same way.  It seems something related to the "Me.Cursor" and something in my form - but I really don´t know what exactly it could be since the form has nothing different from other forms where I utilize the same "Me.Cursor" instruction...